# Is it possible to separate the html content to make it easier in append?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I have a JS function that appends html content to certain tags. The thing is that I have to add more content and hence the complexity arises. Is it possible to separate the pure html without affecting the scope of the variables to magçnage it more easily? I attach the code:

```
function create_slide(element){
  console.log(element);
  if (element.imgdestacado){
    carousel.append(
      "<div class=\"carousel-item\"><img class=\"d-block w-100 darken\" src="+ element.imgdestacado.url +">\
      <div class=\"corner-comercio\"><span>Turismo</span></div>\
      <div class=\"carousel-caption d-none d-md-block\"><h1 class=\"display-1 text-left\">"+ element.titulo +"</h1><p class=\"display-4 text-left\">"+ element.info +"</p></div></div>");
  }
  if (element.imgpromo){
    carousel.append(
      "<div class=\"carousel-item \"><img class=\"d-block w-100\" src="+ element.imgpromo.url +">\
      <div class=\"corner-comercio\"><span>Turismo</span></div>\
      <div class=\"carousel-caption d-none d-md-block\"><h1>Hola</h1><p>Eoooooooooo</p></div></div>");
  }
  if (element.imgevento){
    carousel.append(
      "<div class=\"carousel-item \"><img class=\"d-block w-100\" src="+ element.imgevento.url +">\
      <div class=\"corner-comercio\"><span>Actualidad</span></div>\
      <div class=\"carousel-caption d-none d-md-block\"><h1 class=\"display-1\">"+ element.titulo +"</h1><p class=\"display-4\">"+ element.info +"</p></div></div>");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not exactly understand your question, but would it be easier to use the back tick/back quote so you are able to use multi-lines?

Example:

```
carousel.append(`

<div class="carousel-item">
    <img class="d-block w-100 darken" src="${element.imgdestacado.url}">
    <div class="corner-comercio">
        <span>Turismo</span>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h1 class="display-1 text-left">${element.titulo}</h1>
        <p class="display-4 text-left">${element.info}</p></div>
    </div>
</div>

`);
```